# Getting the value from controller outside the foreach error: Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::

Tags: php, laravel

Cannot get the value outside the foreach.

I want to call the value outside the foreach statement but I cannot call it. But inside the foreach it is working. Whats the possible problem?

//Controller

```
$data['test1'] = ...some query...;
$data['test2'] = ...some query...;
return view ('testpage',['data'=>$data]);
```

//View (Working)

```
  @foreach($data['test1'] as $result) 
    {{$result -> test_val}}
    @endforeach
```

//View (Not Working)

```
 {{$data['test1'] -> test_val}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already got the answer...

Since that i push more than 1 I also need to locate where is index.. so the answer will be
`{{$data['test1'][0] -> test_val}}`

The missing part is [0] or the index of which you want to locate.